# Is it permissible to get a tattoo now that they can be removed

Tags: halacha, tattoo

Now that once permanent tattoos can be removed, that means they are no longer permanent.

So is it now permissible to get a tattoo, why, why not?

Comment: why do assume that to the prohibition to get a tattoo is only because it is permament?

Comment: Good question, I suppoose I just assumed, would you share with me the other reasons?

Comment: well start here i guess: http://www.koltorah.org/ravj/14-21%20Permanent%20and%20Semi-Permanent%20Makeup%20-%20Cosmetic%20Tattooing%203.htm

Comment: just in general, here we try to source our assumptions to our questions

Comment: @chavatzellet I would assume the reason it's prohibited is Because God Said So.

Comment: General Torah rule - sometimes the act itself is what is forbidden, regardless of the result / side affect of the action. If I shoot a cow, I cannot eat it. Now that I removed the bullet from the cow, can I still eat the cow?

Comment: Could you destroy the corner of your beard even if it grows back? Why would being able to remove it be any different?

Comment: because I was under the impression that it was forbidden due to the fact that it cannot be removed. My mistake...it is the etching not the lasting effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sin is not the permanent state of the tattoo. The sin is committed while you are drawing the tattoo.  Leviticus 19:28: “You shall not etch a tattoo on yourselves.”

There is an interesting article Rabbi Dr. Ari Zivotofsky from OU. https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_jews_with_tattoos/ he discusses a lot of points and opinions on temporary tattoos.

Comment: Ahah! Just as I thought. It's the act itself that's the problem. Now, where did that bullet in my bull go??

Comment: @Thank you Banjamin for your comment, that clears things up

Comment: The proof from the verse would only convince me if I was a Karaite, and not a skeptical Karaite, but an accetping Karaite. Were I a skeptical Karaite, I would say that the prohibited act may be getting a tattoo, but perhaps "getting a tattoo" means "permanently imprinting ink on ones skin.

Answer (score 1):

"Permanent" means "will last forever without undergoing any special procedure."

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein writes that even though a tubal ligation can be surgically reversed, it's prohibited as "permanent castration" for precisely this reason.

Comment: Like how dry cleaning doesn't ruin Techelet's permanence.